# Ruby on Rails with twitter APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

Is this possible in Ruby on Rails to update your blog posts on your twitter account using twitter APIs and omniauth. Please suggest me.
More: I have a blog, where i create a new post on blog, this update should go to my twitter account as well as I tweet , this tweet should be shown to my home of blog.
Please suggest me. how it is possible.

Regards,
Vieenay Siingh

Comment: Prepare twitter access token using key, secret and use Twitter API's for updates..

Answer (score 1):

When you post to this website, we are expecting you to have done a background search before.

Anyway, you should find what you need [On the rubygems website](http://rubygems.org/search?query=twitter)

Comment: thanks. Do we need any Twitter API to show user,slatest tweets on blog home page